# Select records with highest salary from duplicate records

Tags: sql, select

Select employee record with highest salary from duplicate records with same name and different salary

```
id|name|salary
1 | A  | 500
2 | B  | 100
3 | A  | 400
3 | B  | 200
```

Output

```
1 | A  | 500
3 | B  | 200
```

Please post the generic sql that will work on all the databases.

I have tried the below query. But this does not return record if duplicate not exist.

```
select e.id,e.name,e.salary FROM employee e,
    employee e1 
WHERE
    e.name = e1.name
    AND e.salary > e1.salary
```

Comment: You should post what you've tried rather than just a question. As posted this does not meet SO rules. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now, i have added what i have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.name, s1.salary
FROM salaries s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM salaries s2
  WHERE s1.name = s2.name AND s1.salary < s2.salary
)
```

Using `ALL`

```
SELECT s1.id, s1.name, s1.salary
FROM salaries s1
WHERE s1.salary >=
ALL(
  SELECT salary
  FROM salaries s2
  WHERE s1.name = s2.name
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reasonable modern database ([mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) being the notable exception) should support window functions. `rank()` should do the trick:

```
SELECT id, name, salary
FROM   (SELECT id, name, salary, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY salary DESC) rk
        FROM   some_table) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server that works (I don't have another SGDB at this time, but it shouldn't be difficult to adapt it):

```
select s.* 
from salaries s
join (
    select name,MAX(salary) as maxsalary 
    from salaries 
    group by name) ms on s.name=ms.name and s.salary=ms.maxsalary
```

the subquery selects rows that represent maximum salaries. The main query filters according to both parameters: name and max salary.